# Get value from View to another controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

i've a unique `controller` where i control it all my views so from here i've got a problem. After to send data to do login i need obtain a value sended. For example, i've this controller: `HomeController`, in this controller i've four `ActionResult`:

> ActionResult Index

> ActionResult Login

> ActionResult Cuotas

> ActionResult LogOff

So, when the user login i need obtain here username to verify is already connected from my DB

**HomeController**:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Login(string uname, string psw)
    {
        try
        {
            ViewData["uname"] = uname;
            ViewData["psw"] = psw;

            ConexionSQL sql = new ConexionSQL();
            var usuario = sql.login(uname, psw);
            var existencia = sql.usuarioOCobrador(uname, psw);

            if (existencia[0].usuario == "USUARIO")
            {
                var caracteres = Convert.ToString(psw);
                var pruebaUsuario = sql.datos(uname);


                if (pruebaUsuario[0].clave == caracteres)
                {
                    return View("Cuotas", usuario);
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Contra = "Contraseña incorrecta.";
                }
            }
            else if (existencia[0].usuario == "COBRADOR")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Cuotas", "Home", usuario);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Usu = "Usuario incorrecto o usted no tiene los permisos para ingresar al sistema. Comuníquese con el área pertinente o el Departamento de Sistemas.";
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return View("Index");
    }

        public ActionResult LogOff(string uname)
        {
            ConexionSQL conexionSQL = new ConexionSQL();
            conexionSQL.updateConectado(uname, false);
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            Session.Abandon();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        public ActionResult Cuotas()
    {
        ConexionSQL sql = new ConexionSQL();
        string uname = string.Empty;
        string psw = string.Empty;

        //Get your ViewData variables here
        if (ViewData["uname"] != null)
        {
            uname = Convert.ToString(ViewData["uname"]);
        }

        if (ViewData["psw"] != null)
        {
            psw = Convert.ToString(ViewData["psw"]);
        }
        var usuario = sql.datosCob(uname);
        if (usuario[0].conectado == false)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Cuotas", "Home");
        }
    }
}
```

Index View, here is the login:

```
        <form class="modal-content animate" onsubmit="return control()" method="post" action="@Url.Action("Login", "Home")">
            <div class="imgcontainer">
                <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Cerrar">&times;</span>
                <img src="~/Images/00.png" alt="Logo" class="avatar"/>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <label for="uname"><b>Usuario:</b></label>
                <input type="text" id="uname" placeholder="Ingrese usuario..." name="uname" onkeypress="return soloLetras(event)"/>

                <label for="psw"><b>Contraseña:</b></label>
                <input type="password" id="psw" placeholder="Ingrese contraseña..." name="psw" onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event)"/>

                <button type="submit">Iniciar sesión</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

But `uname` always is `null`, whats wrong with my code?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to get your `uname` that you first post to your `Login` method and then you need this variable your `Cuotas` method on the same request when the form is submitted? If that is the case then you have to use `Session` to persist your variables from one Controller action to another. Your form action is `Login` method and not `Cuotas` method so your `FormCollection` will always be null. So in your case, it would look like:

```
    public ActionResult Login(string uname, string psw)
    {
        Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
        try
        {
            //Set your variables here to passed to next action
            Session["uname"] = uname;
            Session["psw"] = psw;

            ConexionSQL sql = new ConexionSQL();
            var usuario = sql.login(uname, psw);
            var existencia = sql.usuarioOCobrador(uname, psw);

            if (existencia[0].usuario == "USUARIO")
            {
                var caracteres = Convert.ToString(psw);
                var pruebaUsuario = sql.datos(uname);


                if (pruebaUsuario[0].clave == caracteres)
                {
                    sql.updateConectado(uname, true);
                    return RedirectToAction("Cuotas", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Contra = "Contraseña incorrecta.";
                }
            }
            else if (existencia[0].usuario == "COBRADOR")
            {
                sql.updateConectado(uname, true);
                return RedirectToAction("Cuotas", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Usu = "Usuario incorrecto o usted no tiene los permisos para ingresar al sistema. Comuníquese con el área pertinente o el Departamento de Sistemas.";
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return View("Index");
    }
```

And you can get them in your `Cuotas` method like this:

```
    public ActionResult Cuotas()
    {
        ConexionSQL sql = new ConexionSQL();
        string uname = string.Empty;
        string psw = string.Empty;
        //Get your ViewData variables here
        if (Session["uname"] != null)
        {
          uname = Convert.ToString(Session["uname"]);
        }

        if (Session["psw"] != null)
        {
          psw = Convert.ToString(Session["psw"]);
        }
        var usuario = sql.datosCob(uname);
        if (usuario[0].conectado == false)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Cuotas");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, not worked, uname is "" :/

Comment: @FrancoJoelBalsamo Sorry I was setting your `ViewData` at the wrong point. Please check updated answer.

Comment: Hmm, nop, `uname = ""`

Comment: @FrancoJoelBalsamo Can you please explain what your flow of events is? You send your form data to your `Login` method and then based on your logic, you are doing a redirect to your `Cuotas` method? Can you try setting the `ViewData` just before you make the redirect?

Comment: Well, in order to events. When i run my project first view in load is Index, right? this contains a form to use @Http.URL("Login", "Home") where i send data to validate Login from Controller. After that, if user exists in SQL i redirect to Cuotas event where i load a View or Index, i need show user or validate if user isconected after a time, do you understand me? sorry i don't speak english correctly

Comment: @FrancoJoelBalsamo Can you just redirect without your `Model`: `return RedirectToAction("Cuotas", "Home");` ?

Comment: No, this says not found resource (View) but thw view exists :/

Comment: The last update  from your answer not works to me, and ignore my last comment, it was an error what i'd solutioned

Comment: Nop, uname ="" always, n' i don't know why

Comment: @FrancoJoelBalsamo I have updated my answer to use `Session` for your case. Can you try that?

Comment: Yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeees, with Session it workssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss, thanks n' sorry for stole your time.